# How to catch links with optional spaces in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, regex-group

From a `file_get_contents` I get the HTML code of a url.

```
$html = file_get_contents($url);
```

Now I would like to capture the `href` link.

The HTML code is:

```
<li class="four-column mosaicElement">
<a href="https://example.com" title="Lorem ipsum">
...
</a>
</li>
<li class="four-column mosaicElement">
<a href="https://example.org" title="Lorem ipsum">
...
</a>
</li>
```

So I'm using this:

```
preg_match_all('/class=\"four-column mosaicElement\"><a href=\"(.+?)\" title=\"(.+?)"/m', $html, $urls, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach ($urls as $key => $url) {
    echo $url[1];
}
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: I think you should add a newline `\n` or `\R` after `class=\"four-column mosaicElement\">\R`. https://regex101.com/r/GtBZfG/1 Why not use DOMDocument instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, we can also use an expression with positive lookahead and optional spaces, just in case,

```
(?=class="four-column mosaicElement")[\s\S]*?href="\s*(https?[^\s]+)\s*"
```

and our desired URLs are in this group:

```
(https?[^\s]+)
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/VqygH8/1/)

#### TEST

```
$re = '/(?=class="four-column mosaicElement")[\s\S]*?href="\s*(https?[^\s]+)\s*"/m';
$str = '<li class="four-column mosaicElement">
<a href="https://example.com" title="Lorem ipsum">
...
</a>
</li>
<li class="four-column mosaicElement">
<a href="https://example.org" title="Lorem ipsum">

<li class="four-column mosaicElement">
<a href="   https://example.org   " title="Lorem ipsum">

<li class="four-column mosaicElement">
<a href="   https://example.org                " title="Lorem ipsum">
...
</a>
</li>
';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach ($matches as $key => $url) {
    echo $url[1] . "\n";
}
```

#### Output

```
https://example.com
https://example.org
https://example.org
https://example.org
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use [DOMXPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) with an xpath expression that finds all list items with both class names and then gets the anchors:

```
//li[contains(@class, 'four-column') and contains(@class, 'mosaicElement')]/a
```

For example:

```
$string = <<<DATA
<li class="four-column mosaicElement">
<a href="https://example.com" title="Lorem ipsum">
</a>
</li>
<li class="four-column mosaicElement">
<a href="https://example.org" title="Lorem ipsum">
</a>
</li>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

foreach($xpath->query("//li[contains(@class, 'four-column') and contains(@class, 'mosaicElement')]/a") as $v) {
    echo $v->getAttribute("href") . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Result

```
https://example.com
https://example.org
```

See a [php demo](https://3v4l.org/iuhmP)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get your code working by just modify the regex pattern to the following:

```
class="four-column mosaicElement">\s*<a href="(.+?)" title="(.+?)"
                                 ^^^^^
```

Note carefully that I allow for any amount of whitespace between the `class` attribute from the outer tag (`<li>`) and the inner anchor.

Here is your updated script:

```
$html = "<li class=\"four-column mosaicElement\">\n<a href=\"https://example.com\" title=\"Lorem ipsum\">\n</a>\n</li>\n<li class=\"four-column mosaicElement\">\n<a href=\"https://example.org\" title=\"Lorem ipsum\">\n</a>\n</li>";
preg_match_all('/class="four-column mosaicElement">\s*<a href="(.+?)" title="(.+?)"/m', $html, $urls, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach ($urls as $key => $url) {
    echo $url[1] . "\n";
}
```

This prints:

```
https://example.com
https://example.org
```